# Style image from database as background image

Tags: php

I want to use the image reference I made in the database as a background: url. I've made the design already => [IMG]http://i49.tinypic.com/30ihudz.png[/IMG]. In my current code I use div style in which I retrieve the image, but that doesn´t show up no image. Could somebody please guide me? Thanks in advance.

```
public function displayProduct()
{

if($product = $this->db->query("SELECT id, title, description, price, filename FROM trips ORDER BY id"))
            {
                while ($row = $product->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                        $output .= '<div class="reisbox">';
                                $output .= '<div id="reis_insidebox1" style=" background: url("C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/"'.$row['filename'].' ") width="1000" height="500">';
                                $output .= '<div class="reis_textbox">';
                                $output .= '<h2>'.ucfirst($row['title']).'</h2>';
                                    $output .= '<article>';
                                    $output .=  ucfirst($row['description']);
                                    $output .= '</article>';
                                    $output .= '</div>';
                                $output .= '<div class="rightboxx">';
                                $output .= '<div class="reis_price_box">';
                                $output .= '<div class="reis_price_box_text">';
                                $output .= '&euro;'.$row['price'];
                                $output .= '</div>';
                                $output .= '<div class="more_box">';
                                $output .= '<a href="index.php?page=reis.php&pid='.$row['id'].'"><p>Lees meer..</p></a>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                                $output .='<br />';
                                $output .= '<div id="add">';
                                $output .='<a href="index.php?page=cart.php&action=add&id='.$row['id'].'"><p>Add to cart</p></a>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                        $output .= '</div>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                    }
                    return $output;

                }
        }
```

Comment: You are using a path for the image that is from a windows hard disk; `"C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/"'.$row['filename'].' "` ..is this intended? I suppose you should use a path relative to the site's directory tree, maybe something like `"/img/content/"'.$row['filename'].' "`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to fetch the file from "C:/xampp/.../" you should add a file:/// infront but I guess you simply want to use a relative path, such as "img/content/andthefilenamefromdatabase.png"

And to continue, you are actually closing your `style`-tag with the `"` in your CSS background, you might want to use `'` there or simply skip the string literal completely

With all this is mind, it could look like so:

```
$output .= '<div id="reis_insidebox1" style="background: url(\'img/content/'.$row['filename'].'\')" width="1000" height="500">';
```

Note that I am escaping the `'` in the CSS here, using a backslash.

Comment: It says invalid property value, at element style n chrome, no pic is shown

Comment: How does the generated html look like? The div specifically? I just noticed I missed a closing `"` for the styling, I've updated that now.